# Asymptotic estimate for incomplete gamma function $\gamma(s,x)$, valid for large $x$ and $s$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, special-functions

Let $(s,x) \mapsto \gamma(s,x) := \int_2^x (\log z)^{-s}\mathrm{d}z$ be the incomplete gamma function (I'm not sure about this naming). It is well-known that for large $x \gt 0$,  the following asymptotic estimate is valid

$$
\gamma(1,x) = O(x/\log x).
$$

**Question.** For large $x \gt 0$ and $s \gt 0$, what is an good asymptotic estimate for the integral $\gamma(s,x)$ ?

Comment: This is an incomplete gamma function

Comment: OK, thanks. Corrected. I'm not familiar with the literature and corresponding terminology.

Comment: See https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11 which gives an asymptotic expansion for the upper incomplete gamma function for the case you ask for. Or are you also interested in a proof?